# Set rows and cols for opencv image

Tags: c++, opencv

I made a function to create a thresholding image. The input is in `img` and the output in `out`.  This is my code:

```
void *tresholdImage (CvMat *img, CvMat *out) {
    for (int i = 0; i < img->rows; i++)
        {
        for (int j = 0; j < img->cols; j++)
            {
            double x;
            if (cvGetReal2D(img, i, j) < 128) x = 0; else x = 255;
            cvSetReal2D(out, i, j, x);
            }
        }
    }
```

When calling this function, the image in `out` should have the same size as the image in `img`. I want to automatically set `out`'s size the same as `img`'s.  I add this before the first `for`:

```
out = cvCreateMat(img->rows, img->cols, img->type);
```

but it won't work; the compiler said Bad Flag in `CvGetMat`.
But if I put it in the main function, it works. Anyone can help me ?

Comment: You tag the question with `C++` instead of `C`, so why use the `C` API instead of the moderner and friendlier `C++` API? Like `cv::Mat`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create the result image during this call, you need something like this:

```
CvMat * thresholdImage (CvMat *img) {
  CvMat *out = cvCreateMat(img->rows, img->cols, img->type);
  for (int i = 0; i < img->rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < img->cols; j++) {
      double x;
      if (cvGetReal2D(img, i, j) < 128) x = 0; else x = 255;
      cvSetReal2D(out, i, j, x);
    }
  return out;
}
```

Then you'll use it as:

```
CvMat *out = thresholdImage(img);
```

Comment: stop using CvMat, use cv::Mat

Comment: @llnk: 1) I did not use it in the first place, this was how the question was, and 2) The question was about how to return the image properly; this is not related to whether the guy is using C or C++.  Of course, if he's using C++, your comment is right.